# Impossible to create archive for PPA in 16.04

Tags: ppa, packaging, debuild

I'm trying to update my PPA with my new 16.04 (Kubuntu x64) but I have a problem with the command I use since 13.10.

Here the terminal return:

```
$ debuild -MY_KEY -S -sa --lintian-opts -i
 dpkg-buildpackage -rfakeroot -d -us -uc -S -sa
dpkg-buildpackage: paquet source dpluzz
dpkg-buildpackage: version source 1.5.6.1~ubuntu16.04
dpkg-buildpackage: distribution source xenial
dpkg-buildpackage: source changé par my_name <my@email.fr>                                                    
 dpkg-source --before-build dpluzz                                                                                           
 fakeroot debian/rules clean                                                                                                 
dh clean --with python2                                                                                                      
dh: No compatibility level specified in debian/compat                                                                        
dh: This package will soon FTBFS; time to fix it!                                                                            
dh: Compatibility levels before 4 are no longer supported (level 1 requested)                                                
debian/rules:4 : la recette pour la cible « clean » a échouée                                                                
make: *** [clean] Erreur 2                                                                                                   
dpkg-buildpackage: erreur: fakeroot debian/rules clean a produit une erreur de sortie de type 2
debuild: fatal error at line 1376:
dpkg-buildpackage -rfakeroot -d -us -uc -S -sa failed
```

An idea, someone, please ? :)

Comment: Create a file `debian/compat` and put `9` in it, save it and try again.

Comment: Yeah!! thanks a lot :)
It works with this file!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the error I could notice:

```
dh: No compatibility level specified in debian/compat
dh: This package will soon FTBFS; time to fix it!
dh: Compatibility levels before 4 are no longer supported (level 1 requested)
debian/rules:4 : la recette pour la cible « clean » a échouée
```

It seems you don't have `debian/compat` or you have an empty one. So `debhelper` expected the lowest compatibility level 1 while the current minimum accepted is 4.

See [Chapter 5. Other files under the debian directory](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/maint-guide/dother.en.html#compat)

As you can see here [debhelper](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&section=all&arch=any&keywords=debhelper&searchon=names) is at v9 for all currently supported Ubuntu releases.

To fix it, create a file `debian/compat` and put `9` in it, save it and run `debuild` again.